# Unable to print .pdf document using Windows 8 Reader

Tags: pdf, printing, windows-8

The below code opens a .pdf file in Windows 8 Microsoft Reader, but it does not print the document. This code is executed from 
Kindly let us know if printing cannot be done from command line for Reader.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO seInfo;
ZeroMemory(&seInfo, sizeof(seInfo));
seInfo.cbSize = sizeof(seInfo);
seInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS|SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
seInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
seInfo.lpClass = NULL;
seInfo.lpIDList = NULL;
seInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
seInfo.hwnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
seInfo.lpVerb       = _T("open");
seInfo.lpFile       = (const _TCHAR *)szShortPath;//File name including the path
seInfo.lpParameters = _T("/p");
ShellExecuteEx(&seInfo);
```

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 handy. Does Windows Explorer offer the ability to print the file from its context menu?

Comment: Try calling it by command line in a console, if it does not work, then it won't work either with ShellExecute.

Comment: File cannot be printed from windows explorer context menu. The command does not work from command line

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like Microsoft Reader app does not register a print or printto verb. Probably >>because there isn't a method in the PrintManager class for automated printing. I suggest >>>you to disable the print feature when the registered program for the PDF file type does >>>>not register a pint or printto verb and instruct the user to change the default >>>>>program for PDF files.